# How can we call a shell script function from java by passing arguments and expecting output from shell script function

Tags: java, shell

I want to call a .sh file which has a function inside that from my java code by passing arguments to that .sh file function, Could you please help me on the same

Comment: use a `ProcessBuilder` to start the shell *interpreter* (e.g. `/bin/sh`) giving the .sh file as argument - see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: This is a two-step process: You pass the arguments to your shell script, and the script - which acts kind of a `main` function - then invokes the shell function with those parameters. Since a shell function by design is meant to be executed inside a shell process, there is no way to call it directly from Java. For the same reason, a shell program can't call an arbitrary Java function. It needs to create a Java process, which runs `main`, and your main function then can call other Java functions.